# I want to know how to include an outside script in inDesign idjs file. When it was extend script I used //@include

Tags: import, include, require, adobe-indesign, uxp-script

I want to be able to import or require inside of inDesign idjs script.

I have tride require, import, and //@include

Comment: It looks like it's a first question about UXP scripts -- a new generation of Extendscript. I just added the new tag `uxp-script`

Comment: Probably the proper answer is here '13:12 – Splitting code' section of this video: https://youtu.be/LkWfEC7bqdE?list=PLRR5kmVeh43alNtSKHUlmbBjLqezgwzPJ&t=798

Comment: On the other hand: https://blog.developer.adobe.com/announcing-uxp-scripting-in-photoshop-beta-65e7e6f1331f it says _Currently, inter-script communication is not possible. A script cannot invoke another script._ So perhaps you can only read file and eval it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.evalFile(File("MY_OTHER_EXTENDSCRIPT_FILE"));
```